# Pandas: groupby - aggregate - expanding

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group1":["A", "A", "A","B","A","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","B"], 
                    "group2":["1", "1", "2","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2"],
                    "date":['2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', 
'2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02','2022-11-01',  '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02'], 
"value":np.random.randint(10, high=50, size=13)})
```

[image]

I want to calculate the cumulative count, cumulative mean and cumulative variance over "date", grouped by "group1" and "group2".

The following lines of code does the trick, but I find it quite clumsy.
Is there a better way ?

```
# sort
tmp = df.sort_values(["date", "group1", "group2"])
# cum mean
tmp2 = tmp.groupby(["group1", "group2"])["value"].expanding().mean().reset_index() 
# cum var
tmp2["var"] = tmp.groupby(["group1", "group2"])["value"].expanding().var().values
# set old index in order to get the date from original df
tmp2 = tmp2.reset_index().set_index("level_2")
tmp2 = pd.concat([tmp["date"], tmp2], axis=1).drop(['index'], axis=1) # remove "index" col
# get the cum mean and cum var for each date
tmp2 = tmp2.groupby(["group1", "group2", "date"]).agg(cnt=("value", "count"), mean=("value", "last"), var=("var", "last")).reset_index()
# create cum count column
tmp2["cumcnt"] = tmp2.groupby(["group1", "group2"])["cnt"].cumsum()
# group by
tmp2.groupby(["group1", "group2", "date"]).last()
```

Which returns the following data frame

[image]

Comment: seed your generated data, so that it is reproducible : `np.seed(123)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby with [transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) could be helpful, that way you don't loose the date column.

The calculation of a running variance will need a couple more intermediary column calculations but should be possible in a similar manner.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"group1":["A", "A", "A","B","A","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","B"], 
    "group2":["1", "1", "2","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2"],
    "date":['2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02','2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02'],
    "value":np.random.randint(10, high=50, size=13)})
df['one'] = 1

df['count_per_date'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2','date'],as_index=True)['one'].transform(sum)
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2'],as_index=True)['value'].transform(np.cumsum)
df['cumcount'] = df.groupby(['group1','group2'],as_index=True)['count_per_date'].transform(np.cumsum)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, transform looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I let the multi-index perspective because there would be too many NAN-holes.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"group1":["A", "A", "A","B","A","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","B"], 
                    "group2":["1", "1", "2","1","2","2","2","1","2","1","1","1","2"],
                    "date":['2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-01', '2022-11-01', 
'2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02','2022-11-01',  '2022-11-01', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02', '2022-11-02'], 
"value":np.random.randint(10, high=50, size=13)})

g = df.groupby(['group1', 'group2', 'date'])

cumsum = pd.DataFrame( g["value"].expanding().sum().rename("cumsum") )
cummean = pd.DataFrame( g["value"].expanding().mean().rename("cummean") )
cumvar = pd.DataFrame( g["value"].expanding().var().rename("cumvar") )

r = pd.concat([cumsum, cummean, cumvar], axis=1)

r['cumcount'] = r.groupby(['group1', 'group2']).cumcount()+1

print(r)
```

```
                             cumsum  cummean  cumvar  cumcount
group1 group2 date                                            
A      1      2022-11-01 0     25.0     25.0     NaN         1
                         1     68.0     34.0   162.0         2
              2022-11-02 10    33.0     33.0     NaN         3
                         11    77.0     38.5    60.5         4
       2      2022-11-01 4     42.0     42.0     NaN         1
              2022-11-02 2     30.0     30.0     NaN         2
B      1      2022-11-01 3     42.0     42.0     NaN         1
                         9     63.0     31.5   220.5         2
              2022-11-02 7     42.0     42.0     NaN         3
       2      2022-11-01 5     48.0     48.0     NaN         1
                         8     85.0     42.5    60.5         2
              2022-11-02 6     41.0     41.0     NaN         3
                         12    62.0     31.0   200.0         4
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I may have not been clear enough, but I need the cumulative sum, mean and variance to run over all days prior. For example, for group1=A and group2=1 the "cumvar" should only be NaN for the first row in date="2022-11-01". The calculated "cumvar" for date="2022-11-02" should therefore include the values of the previous dates, hence no NaN. This is why I do not group by date when calculating the cumulative count, mean and variance in my suggested method.